# Film about people in a rural area trapped behind a force field

Tags: story-identification, movie, force-field

I remember watching a film in the late 70s or early 80s about people in a rural area who were trapped in a force field and could not escape. There were scenes of them digging out dirt along the edge to get to the bottom of the barrier.

Answer (score 10):

There's a 1966 movie called [*The Bubble*](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0060396/) that was re-released in 1976; a husband and wife (Mark and Catherine), and the pilot (Tony) of the plane they were on end up in the titular bubble.  There's a scene where Tony and Mark try to dig their way out of the bubble.

Quoting the [plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bubble_(1966_film)) on Wikipedia;

> When the outsiders try to leave, **they discover the town is encased in a gigantic clear dome**. Mark hypothesizes that aliens are studying the townspeople, and sitting in the rock seat keeps the townspeople alive (as no food is getting in). A massive shadow passes over the town, and a woman and her child are pulled into the air. Hysterical, Catherine hides with her baby in an old mill on the edge of town.
>
> **Mark and Tony decide to try to dig a tunnel under the dome**. In frustration, Mark takes a sledgehammer to the throne. The shadow passes over and Tony is taken by the aliens. Realizing he has little time left before the aliens come for him, Mark starts frantically digging and finds the bottom of the dome.

Comment: thanks David!  I hope I can find a copy of it online to watch!!

Comment: There's also the Stephen King novel and subsequent TV series [Under the Dome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Under_the_Dome_(TV_series)), but that's probably too recent to be what the OP is thinking of.  (The book was from 2009, and the show was 2013-15, so definitely not around in the 80's.)

Comment: Another movie that could be a good match if it weren't too recent is the 2012 Austrian movie [_Die Wand_ (The Wall)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1745686/?ref_=fn_al_tt_7), in which a woman visiting the countryside wakes up to find an invisible wall cutting her off from the rest of the world (and of humanity). Restricted to an area a few miles across, she has to work out how to survive until the wall vanishes again — if it does… It's slow, bleak, beautiful, thought-provoking, and very memorable.